# Is it possible to call 2.x code from 3.x code in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have code written in python 2.6 that is using(depending on) other third-party libraries that are written in python 2.6 also. These third-party libraries are old and won´t be translated to python 3.x in a near future or in some cases never. My question is if it is possible to write 3.x code that can call code(functions) from the 2.6 code.

ex: write 3.x python code that can call 2.6 code that in turn calls the third-party libraries and returns the result if there is any back to the 3.x code.

If you have any examples or know if this is possible or not or can point me in the right direction it would be great.

Thank you for your time

Comment: You might want to look in to 2to3 http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html

Comment: In general, it's not the best idea to to depend on old, unsupported third-party libraries. Are you sure there aren't Python 3 libraries that accomplish a similar task?

Comment: @Max who says those libraries are unsupported?

Comment: @Max I agree unfortunately i have no option in this case, yes searched and talked to the creators on the mailing lists but sadly there are none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. Port the libraries yourself - this isn't as hard as it might seem, although not ideal.
2. Use some kind of IPC to interface between python 3.x and 2.x installations.
3. Just stick with python 2.x

I'd recommend option 3, for the reasons you identify - it looks like a lot of libraries are only going to be available for 2.x. Frankly, there aren't any compelling reasons to switch to 3.x.

Update: you have a fourth option, which is to use something like PyPi to create a python executable which can cope with running the two languages at once. If the languages seriously end up with a split between sets of essential libraries, then someone will probably do this.

Comment: Option 3 may make sense for the near term, but libraries *are* switching.  In the long term it's going to be Python 3 for sure; the only question is how soon.  Django 1.6 will fully support Python 3.x, and SciPy is working on Python 3.x support.

Comment: @steveha I'll believe it when I see it.

Comment: I have been using Python 3 for all my personal projects and some professional projects for quite a while now with only minor issues regarding library availability.

Comment: @dom0 I'm incredibly happy for you.

Comment: @Marcin Oh ah sarcasm detector. A real useful invention.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an IPC framework wrapping all your calls transparently. You could try using Pyro4 for that, but I'm not sure if that is going to work.